# Vaadin checkbox onValueChange

Tags: java, checkbox, vaadin

i have a code which controls filter on displaying table. For filtering user should click on checkBox and then see filtered results.For some reason user has to click on checkbox and then click outside of checkbox to see response.

```
  getView().getCheckBoxAllSeasons().addValueChangeListener(new ValueChangeListener() {
        public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
            loadTable();
            getView().getDateFieldSeason().setEnabled(!getView().getCheckBoxAllSeasons().getValue());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you set the checkbox to immediate? `checkBox.setImmediate(true);`

Answer (score 0):

checkBox.setImmediate(true) - that did it!